# Obfuscate part of an Android Project

Tags: java, android, obfuscation

I would like to obfuscate and convert to a library part of my Android Project in order to make it available for other developers.

The part I would like to obfuscate is our propriatory algorithm. The algorithm is pure java and gets an input from the android application and returns some output to the application and it is using an API style.

Can someone point me a resource where I can read and split my algorithm from the Android Application and create an obfuscated an reusable JAR file?

Please keep in mind that my Algorithm is pure java thus I believe that I do not need to create an Android Library. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: may be this will [help](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: Should I use option 8 ? Just create a Java Project . Use eclipse to export the jar and then use proguard using the configuration in option 8? Which settings should I use when creating the jar file through eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102688/how-to-create-an-obfuscated-jar-file